# How to get an id of a newly inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently working on school project and am developing a simple discussion forum. I have a problem right now, I want to get the id of the newly inserted row of a user once the user asks a question and I will also like to pass the id to another page and display then question. What I really want is something similar with this stackoverflow when you post a question it take to another page and display it. Please how can I achieve this, any help is welcome.
the id is auto increment

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["title"]) && isset($_POST["question"]) ){
$title = $_POST["title"];
$ask = $_POST["question"];

$sql = $con->prepare("insert into question(userid,title,question)values(?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('iss',$userid,$title,$ask);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
  }?>
```

i just used the code post the question but i don't know what next.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from:

> From the manual for [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) :
>
> `mysqli::$insert_id` -- `mysqli_insert_id` — Returns the auto generated id used in the latest query

```
$sql->insert_id();
```

To pass on to other pages, you can set the last inserted ID to a session variable and get it later. One way is like this:

**`insert.php`**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Other codes

    $sql->execute();
    $_SESSION["last_id"] = $sql->insert_id();
```

And in the next file...

**`next.php`**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Other codes

    $sql->execute();
    $_SESSION["last_id"]; // has the previous inserted ID.
```